# http redirect only first directory name will change

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have trouble with redirection.

I have /confs/2014/[month]/[city]/[shortname]/ for example:

```
     /confs/2014/06/london/icamme/
     /confs/2014/09/paris/icadd/
     /confs/2014/10/losangles/icamad/
```

I have 12 months, 80 city, numerous shortnames, under them there are real html files. I want to redirect them to php sys. Php expects format of

```
/conf/2014/[month]/[city]/[shortname]/
```

I tried this below

```
RewriteRule ^conferences\/2014\/(.*) conference/2014/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but it doesn't redirect

Comment: Unable to get it, can you try explaining your problem again?

Comment: What didn't work? I was requesting you to explain your problem clearly :)

Comment: There are no RewriteRules containing `confs` or `conf`. How do you expect the first url to be rewritten to the second one? You also don't have any external redirects, just internal rewrites. You need the `[R]` flag for external redirects. See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.